# How can I allocate enough memory for this program to m_fork in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, irix

I have an application running on IRIX which uses [m_fork()](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/m_fork.3p.html) to create a number of processes. [Source code.](https://gist.github.com/flotwig/1646d5bc60f8b0ac16af)

When I run the application with 3 forks, everything works as expected. When I ask for four forks, it fails to fork with an "ENOMEM" error:

```
bash-2.05$ ./hello 3
 Process spawn limit is  8
 Hello world from process 1
 Hello world from process 2
 Hello world from process 0
 2nd line: Hello world from process 1
 2nd line: Hello world from process 2
 2nd line: Hello world from process 0
bash-2.05$ ./hello 4
 Process spawn limit is  8
m_fork() did not work
```

I know this is a memory allocation issue because when I throw in `malloc(900000000);` right before `m_fork()`, everything works as expected.

While this does fix the problem, it's not a suitable solution because it's just an arbitrarily large number. How can I dynamically allocate just enough memory for the forks?

e: The core question I'm trying to get answered here is, "how can I allocate enough memory for the forks?"

Comment: Why would burning memory help *avoid* an OOM error? You should investigate that. How could allocating memory and not using it possibly help?

Comment: My impression was that when I malloc the memory, m_fork then uses it for the forks. It does fix the problem though, so it helps. I'm asking the proper way to do it because I realize that's not an appropriate solution.

Comment: Hi @user3474615, if your claim above is correct, why would 3 procs execute and 4 not without explicit memory allocation?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you know? My *guess* is that the first three forks are able to fit within the initial memory allocation, but the fourth one tips the scales. Which is why the malloc "fixes" it. If you look at the source code linked, there is no memory allocation done whatsoever.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, but an important thing to realize is that **IRIX m_fork() is quite different than plain unix fork()**.

Comment: From the m_fork() man page (http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/p_man/cat3p/m_set_procs.z)
The processes are created using the sproc(2) system call, and share all attributes (virtual address space,file descriptors, uid, etc.).

Check out the fourth paragraph of sproc(2) below. I think this holds the answer, but I don't have an IRIX machine I can test this on. Good luck! 
http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?cmd=getdoc&coll=0650&db=man&fname=2%20sproc

Comment: fork cannot use random application memory for its purposes. You might be using that memory. This theory is false.

Comment: @usr, can you offer an alternative explanation as to why it works with the large malloc call?

Comment: @MylesBaker thanks for the pointer. I'll check it out some more, although strace shows the system call as being a regular sproc call. Not sure if I can affect the arguments to that too much.

Comment: No, because I know almost nothing about fork. But I can show that the existing theory is not right.

Comment: @usr, please do. I'm very new to C and I don't have a solid grasp of memory.

Comment: `printf("m_fork() did not work \n")` is not very informative. Print `strerror(errno)` instead.

Comment: @user58697, as described in the problem it is an ENOMEM error.